# convert an array and an array of arrays into array of objects with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array (columns) and an array of arrays (rows of cell data).
I need to merge and convert them into an array or object of objects, where each object comprises of key value pairs.

so from something like this

`var columns = ['col 1', 'col 2', 'etc']`

and

`var rows = [arr1[], arr2[], arr3[]]`

`// where arr1.length === columns.length`

My result needs to be something like

`var result = [
        {
            'col 1':arr1[0].value,
            'col 2':arr1[1].value,
            ...etc
        },
        {
            'col 1':arr2[0].value,
            'col 2':arr2[1].value,
            ...etc

        }
   ];`

I hope this makes sense.
Thanks for your help people!

Comment: explain to me what you've tried, and I'll explain where you went wrong.

Comment: seems simple enough. What's your question?

Comment: And what's the particular problem you have doing so? Do you know how to iterate over arrays?

Comment: yes, but when I try to create the object and access array elements as arr1[0] etc - I get an error, plus I kinda need to go with a double iteration, - I have a fear this is recursion territory that is still a mindfark to me :(

Comment: Show your code. What's the error? There's no recursion needed. All you need is a loop inside a loop.

Comment: oh, the particular problem is of Google's fusion table - the autogenerated map takes a click eventlistener and returns an object with key:value pairs, but I also have to populate a table with teh same data, so I wrote a sql query, but that returns an array of array - I need my data to be always in the same structure bc there are multiple ways to interact and get data (via search or via the map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "oneliner", just for fun:

```
var columns = ['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3'];

var rows = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
];

var result = rows.map(function(row) {
    return this.reduce(function(result, column, columnIndex) {
        result[column] = row[columnIndex];
        return result;
    }, {});
}, columns);

console.log(result);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KkWX4/2/

Comment: I don't think that's what he's after. Pretty sure that each nested Array in `rows` has a `.length` equal to `columns.length`, and that it's a simple mapping of key  `columns[i]` to value `current_row[i]`. I think you've got it turned sideways.

Comment: Looks like I mixed up my spec a bit - let me see if I can wrangle this around a little (matching wrong cols and rows) - but the concept seems ok - I'll post back ASAP

Comment: What I get right now is an array of objects, the keys are correctly populated from the column names, but the values are wonky: the first object gets values from the first column, the second object gets values form the second column etc - so yes it's a bit sideways

Comment: Deleting my answer. This one's all yours. Have fun! :-D

Comment: nope - wait a sec please @cookiemonster I changed:

    `// row[column] = rows[columnIndex][rowIndex];`
to
    `row[column] = rows[rowIndex][columnIndex];`

and that's doing the right thing, only it stops the iteration at the length of columns, not at the length of rows, so I keep going - it's almost there I think

Comment: @datafunk: the solution is much simpler then

Comment: That's the one - thanks @zerkms - clearly I made a booboo in my specking the question.

Comment: gooosh - that's not yet it, sorry - now I have an object of just values, not key:value pairs

Comment: @datafunk: have you checked my jsfiddle?

Comment: yes and that looks ok - let me just comb through my implementation again

Comment: ok, sorry - it's correct, apologies for the confusion & chaos!